# Java: Getting the Value of the User Input that Threw an Exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I'm trying to catch an InputMismatchException with the Scanner expecting a double, and if the input is equal to "c" or "q" I want to do run some specific code in the catch block. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the value of the user input after an exception has been thrown. So for example, if the code calls for a double and the user enters the letter "c", I want to be able to know that specifically "c" was input, and do something if true. Here's the code I'm trying to write, where "getValue()" is a made-up method name to describe what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
double value = 0.0;

try{
    System.out.print("\nEnter a number: ");
    value = input.nextDouble();
}
catch(InputMismatchException notADouble){
    if(notADouble.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("c")){
        //run the specific code for "c"
    }
    else if(notADouble.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("q")){
        //run the specific code for "q"
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("\nInvalid Input");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your input :)

Comment: Check out the Double.parseDouble() function, you will use that with Scanner.next() or Scanner.nextLine();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Scanner.hasNextDouble()` to validate the input before Scanner tries to convert it to a number.  Something like this should work:

```
  double value = 0.0;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("\nEnter a number: ");
     while(input.hasNext())
     {
        while(input.hasNextDouble())
        {
           value = input.nextDouble();
        }

        String next = input.next();

        if("c".equals(next))
        {
           //do something
        }
        else if("q".equals(next))
        {
           //do something
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.print("\nInvalid Input");
           //return or throw exception

        }
     }
```

Comment: I completely forgot about the hasNext methods, and they are exactly what I needed. +1 
So now that I know this, I wonder, is there ever any reason to need to try/catch user input, or does the Scanner class have pretty much every method one would require to prevent input exceptions?

Comment: If scanner has a matching hasNext() method for every next() - I haven't verified this, but looks true at a glance - you could preemptively check the input before every next() call.  But that is probably mildly expensive, and there are cases for Scanner like scanning very large files that must meet a spec, where using the exception to terminate versus pre-emptive checking provides better performance.

Answer (score -1):

You should read in the input as a String, then do a conversion.